# The connection string 'ClinlabEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, iis-8

I am using IIS 8 and MVC4 Application I am having an error..

Thank You for your Help. 
[image]

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ClinlabConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\sql2012;Initial Catalog=Clinlab;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection string in the message error `ClinlabEntities` is not the same that you posted `ClinlabConnectionString1`, you should look for `ClinlabEntities` connection string and add the `providerName` attribute.